# Are Meliodas and Elizabeth still in love after he becomes the demon king?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

When Meliodas becomes the demon king, he becomes cold and blunt towards Elizabeth and even makes a statement that he doesn’t feel anything when she hugs him anymore.

Is that just a result of Meliodas being in his demonic form without his emotions, or has he really fallen out of love with Elizabeth and just wants to end their curses so he can be free of her? Will he want to be with her in the afterlife?

Does he still love her, or is he just keeping his promise to break their curses?

Answer (score 2):

The reason he is cold towards Elizabeth is because

> the demon king removes his emotions and imprisons them in Purgatory when he is killed by Estarossa and the other Commandments. The Meliodas that returns to life is without feelings, and is just keeping his promise.

However, in the latest arcs (Manga spoilers; not in the anime yet)

> Ban journeys to Purgatory and successfully manages to prison break Meliodas' feelings. Though they get split up on the way out, it is clear that both of them managed to escape. Thus, with his feelings restored, Meliodas should love Elizabeth again as before.